# How do phantom types work with newtype?

Tags: haskell, newtype, phantom-types

My understanding of newtypes is that they are compiled out by GHC. However, this can't be the whole story because phantom types can hold information.

From [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype):

> you can wrap [a type] in a newtype and it'll be considered distinct to the type-checker, but identical at runtime. You can then use all sorts of deep trickery like phantom or recursive types without worrying about GHC shuffling buckets of bytes for no reason.

For example, imagine a newtype representing arithmetic modulo q:

```
newtype Zq q = Zq Int

class Modulus q where
    getModulus :: q -> Int

addZq :: (Modulus q) => Zq q -> Zq q -> Zq q
addZq (Zq a) (Zq b) = Zq $ (a+b) `mod` (getModulus (undefined :: q))
```

`addZq` can't be compiled down to

```
addZq :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

so in what sense is the newtype compiled out, and where does the phantom type information get stored?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The thing to keep in mind is that you don't "compile down" to Haskell; you compile down to some other, more explicit language -- in GHC's case, the next well-known step down is core. And although you can't compile `addZq` down to something of type `Int -> Int -> Int` in Core, you *can* compile it down to something whose type you might write as `Modulus q => Int -> Int -> Int`. In this more explicit language, `=>` has a different meaning than in Haskell; in this language, `c => t` is the type of a function which takes evidence (in this case, a class dictionary) for the claim `c` and produces something of type `t`. So `Modulus q => Int -> Int -> Int` is roughly the same as `(q -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int`, and `addZq` certainly *can* be given that type, even in Haskell.

Comment: Even further steps down, "roughly" the same becomes *exactly* the same.  See the [reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package for a mind-bending example of how to cheat with this to get around Haskell's lack of runtime-generated instances.

Answer (score 4):

When newtypes are said to be compiled out by GHC, this means only means runtime behavior.  Specifically, they are guaranteed not to be slower than the same code without the `newtype`.  But they still carry on the type information throughout the compilation process, including when used as phantom types.

In other words, a newtype is compile-time information only, and that's good enough for phantom types to work.